including the material [commodity] means for this

The notion that “development” is synonymous with “economic growth”
has, however, been subjected to severe criticism. By far the most
significant is that of Amartya Sen, who has argued that
“commodities”—the production of which is a major part of economic
growth—are only of value to us in terms of what they allow us actually
to do. Sen advocates that we should think about development rather in
terms of people’s capability to achieve those things that they have
reason to value: “The focus here is on the freedom that a person
actually has to do this or be that—things that he or she may value
doing or being” (Sen 2009: 231, emphasis added). It is inherent in
this approach that freedoms, both the “negative” freedoms—being free
from unjustified coercion, and freedoms of speech and expression, of
association, and of movement—and the “positive” freedoms, which have
to do with what makes it possible for people actually to enjoy their
freedom (including the material [commodity] means for this), are of
fundamental importance. According to this view, therefore, development
“can be seen as a process of expanding the real freedoms that people
enjoy”
(from International Development: Ideas, Experience, and Prospects)

In the bolded phrase 'including the material [commodity] means for this',

Of which is 'the material [commodity] means' an example? An example of 'what makes it possible for people actually to enjoy their freedom'? Or anything else?

What does 'this' after 'including the material [commodity] means for' refer to? 'making it possible for people actually to enjoy their freedom'? or just 'for people actually to enjoy their freedom'? Or anything else?



Will you please add a link or some other complete reference to the original text?
As quoted '…what makes it possible for people actually to enjoy their freedom (including the material [commodity] means for this), are of fundamental importance…' is hardly acceptable English…

The passage states that having both negative and positive freedoms are of "fundamental importance". Several examples of negative freedoms are listed. Positive freedoms are not as clearly indicated.
This portion of the passage refers specifically to positive freedoms:

the “positive” freedoms, which have to do with what makes it possible
for people actually to enjoy their freedom (including the material
[commodity] means for this),

Positive freedoms are those "freedoms" that make it possible for people to enjoy their freedom, i.e. the pursuit of happiness. Without both positive freedoms AND possession of money or other tangible, marketable assets, ("material means"), it isn't possible for people to pursue happiness.
At many times in the past, the right to own property or wear well-made clothing and gold jewelry was a privilege available to only a select few. Jews who lived in the Pale of Settlement were not allowed to be property owners. English people who were not gentry weren't allowed to wear nice clothes and gold accessories in the Middle Ages. In both cases, it didn't matter if they had sufficient money (the material means), as they didn't have the freedom to buy or own such things.
Likewise, material means are necessary to actualize the positive freedoms: Having the right to own property and wear gold isn't sufficient on its own to do so.
It can be determined that the author of the passage is associating both "what makes it possible for people actually to enjoy their freedom" and "the material [commodity] means" with positive freedoms because of the comma that is immediately prior to "are of fundamental importance."

Thank you. Then, the answer to "What includes 'the material means[commodity] means for this'?" is 'what makes it possible for people actually to enjoy their freedom'?

What does 'this' after 'including the material [commodity] means for' indicate? Would you quote or use the original as much as possible and answer explicitly?

@Mcreaper sorry, I for the delay. I just visited English SE again now. What you asked in your first comment (on Aug 27 at 16:16) is correct. In other words, yes, that is the answer. I hope this helps clarify.
